# java read from list and return matches

Tags: java

I am facing an issue. Below you can see my code. The code asks user to input length of the word. When read the program then read test.txt and save all words of appropriate length to arraylist. What i need next is to offer a user a choice to input a word he is searching lets say input is D*g. Program would read from list!! not txt file and search from all possible mathces and return them (exm. Dig, Dag, Dog,...). Any ideas how to do that?

```
package test;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class proba {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList listA = new ArrayList();
       System.out.println("Vnesi dožino besede, ki jo iščeš");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int dolzina = in.nextInt();
        try {

            File file = new File("test.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String vrstica;
         while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {    
            if (vrstica.length()==dolzina){
                listA.add(vrstica);
        }
    }                
    System.out.println("Vnesi besedo, za neznano črko vpiši *.");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String vnos=input.nextLine();

    bufferedReader.close();
    }        
         catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();         

 }}}
```

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: yes but how to read from list

Comment: and how would user input words? character by character? lets say D then enter * then enter and g and enter? or could it be in one like like D*g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to have a regular expression to make the search with:

```
string vnos = input.nextLine();
string myPattern = vnos.replace("*","."); //Replaces * with the wildcard regex character, "."
```

You can use this to get a regular expression from the user. To search through the List, you want to use a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++)
{
    if (listA.get(i).matches(myPattern))
    {
        System.out.println(listA.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but doesnt myPattern = vnos.replace("*","."); replaces 0 or more characters? i need when * is inputred to replace exactly 1 character. D*g cannot match Doog

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your use-case is strictly related to what you've asked (simple expressions like "D*g") the simplest solution would be to use directly the *match* method with your input as parameter, replacing the * with the dot.

```
....
String vnos=input.nextLine();
vnos = vnos.replace("*","/.");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
//Iterates on string list
for (int i=0; i<listA.size(); i++){
    String s = (String)listA.get(i);
    if (s.matches(vnos))
        results.add(s);
}
```

However, for more complex cases, you need to translate the user input into a valid regular expression yourself (or rely upon a library for the translation).

I suggest you a good tutorial which can be usefull to understand regular expression in a Java environment, as well as more complex examples.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: manage to make it work thank you